# Clearing a nested setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Having some trouble clearing a setInterval which is nested within another setInterval.

`polling` is cleared just fine, but `marque` (which is set globally) keeps on firing even though cleared is spit out in the console multiple times.

```
listener: function() {
    var polling;

    journalScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
        clearInterval(polling);
        Roots.common.journal.scroll.status();
        console.log('scrollend');
    });

    journalScroll.on('scrollStart', function() {
      polling = setInterval(Roots.common.journal.scroll.status, 1250); // Time in milliseconds
      console.log('scrollstart');
    });
},

status: function() {
  console.log('scroll status');

  if((journalScroll.y*-1) < $(window).height() * 3) {
    console.log('setinterval');
    marque = setInterval(function() {
      Roots.common.journal.scroll.marque();
    }, 50);
  } else {
    clearInterval(marque);
    console.log('cleared');
  }
},

marque: function() {
  console.log('polling marque');        
},
```

Comment: You can just insert a check to see if an interval is already assigned to marque and if it is, clear it before adding a new one.

Comment: I just went with clearing before setInterval. Not the cleanest way but did the thing. Thanks. (@Emissary, maybe add it as an answer so I can accept it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` simply returns an ID (integer) and will attempt to run a timer indefinitely until you pass that same ID back to the `clearInterval` function.  Due to the relatively unpredictable nature of ***events*** and ***asynchronous*** functionality, calls and callbacks can often result in [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

For example, your code may be creating a new interval and assigning a different ID to the `marque` variable before the old interval had been cleared - this results in it being "orphaned" as it is still running and you have no ID with which to cancel it.

Without seeing all of your code the simplest way of "fixing" the issue would be to blindly  `clearInterval(marque);` before you `setInterval` in your `status` function - ensuring that for this case only one interval is active at any point in time.